# Pinch zoom in Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a html page containing divs. Each divs contains some information.

```
Name : John Doe           //First div (First-level Information)
Name : Jane Doe           //Second div (First-level Information)
Name : Lorem Ipsum        //Third div (First-level Information)
```

Originally the information that will be seen is only name of the person.
When someone `pinch zooms` the **div** that particular div should **expand/scale** itself to display **more information.**

```
Name : John Doe
Age  : 23                 //First div (Second-level Information)
Name : Jane Doe     
Age  : 25                 //Second div (Second-level Information)
Name : Lorem Ipsum    
Age  : 31                 //Third div (Second-level Information)
```

In short, I want to have same behavior as **Google maps** have.

So my question is, which javascript library should I use to implement this.

Comment: why pinch zoom? why not a simple touch?

Comment: actually, my requirement is to have both, i.e. zoom on multi-touch and pinch zoom. If you know any, pls let me know.

Comment: So use the answer I gave, 'hammer.is' is really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/)

> Hammer is a open-source library that can recognize gestures made by touch, mouse and pointerEvents. It doesn't have any dependencies, and it's small, only 3.96 kB minified + gzipped!